# Ubuntu LTS 16.04 Install problems: UEFI and Black Screen after Grub Loader

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi

Good afternoon, all.

I have a PC that currently has Windows 10 on it, and I would like to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. However, I am having some issues:

When I boot to the live media, I get the Boot Loader screen where I am asked if I would like to Install Ubuntu, or Try Before Installing. When I select either option, I get a black screen, and I have to restart my machine.

Here is what I have done:

I have disabled Fast Boot In Windows 10
I have disabled secured boot
I have tried with Fast Boot disabled, and Secure Boot enabled
I have booted in legacy mode and checked 'nomodeset' (while doing this I can get to the Ubuntu Desktop on my live medium, however I can not use my keyboard and mouse, even with the setting to allow that (can't remember which) is enabled in the BIOS.

I am looking to install Ubuntu cleanly, as in format the SSD of the windows install with only an Ubuntu Install.

What am I missing?

I am running an AMD FX processor with a Gigabyte Motherboard.

Comment: Boot in UEFI mode, and at the grub screen, type "e" to edit and on the vmlinuz line, insert the "nomodeset" instead of the "quiet splash". to see if that works.  What video hardware do you have?

Comment: The problem is difficult to reproduce without further details about the hardware and error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Try with an older version of Ubuntu and upgrade.

Also try a rolling distribution.

Looks like a driver or hardware problem. Best to take an older release and if that doesn't work another os.

Answer (score 0):

I found this somewhere on the Ubuntu forms and it's worked for me.  I was having USB issues and the Ethernet port wasn't working.

**Edit:**  I apologize.  If your board has USB3 ports, they should work so that you can apply the fix.  My problem (and solution) is based on the fact my USB2 ports were not working and my USB3 ports did work.  So I was able to plug in my USB keyboard and mouse to a USB3 port and work from there.

I have a [GA-970A-D3P](http://www.gigabyte.us/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5193&kw=GA-970A-D3P2.x#ov), and the original solution came from someone running another one in a similar series.

So here you go.

After installing Ubuntu, open a terminal.  Run the command:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Look for the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Now edit it to read:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=soft"
```

Save changes to grub, exit gedit and terminal.

Open a new terminal screen, run the following command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

exit terminal, restart computer.

Everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as Dillon Willis on my Dell Inspiron laptop. I followed the suggestion in Ubfan1's comment and succeeded in installing Ubuntu 16.04 to dual-boot with Windows 10. Ubuntu was there, but would not boot normally. It did boot in Recovery Mode. So I booted, and in Terminal added a program called "Boot Customizer". Then I used Boot Customizer to make Ubfan1's change permanent in the Grub file. Ubuntu 16.04 now boots normally. Windows 10 says that my graphics card is a "Gallium 0.4 on Livmpipe (LLVM 3.8 128  bits").